# for loop create a list around "x" based on "n"

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, range

Basically trying to figure out how to create a for loop that generates a range around a the main number "x" based on "n"

```
x = 10                  # x = Actual
n = 5
```

because

```
Actual = input("What's the Actual")  # Enter 10
Target = input("What's the Target")  # Enter 15



n = Target - Actual  # 5 = 15 - 10
```

Since Actual is 10

I would like to see..

```
5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

The code is:

```
n = 2
def price(sprice):
     for i in range(n*2):
        sprice = sprice + 1
        print(sprice)

price(200)
```

This code shows `201,202,203,204` and the actual is 200.
I want to see `198,199,200,201,202` because `n = 2` and when multiply by 2 = 4 which shows a range of 4 values around 200

Answer (score 3):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#range), `range` can accept two argument that specify the start (inclusive) and end (exclusive) of the interval. So you can get an interval in the form `[start, stop)`.

You would like to create the interval `[Actual - n, Actual + n]`, so just translate it almost literally to Python, bearing in mind that `range` *excludes* the second argument from that range, so you should add one to it:

```
>>> list(range(Actual - n, Actual + n + 1))
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: That was really fast! That really help! Just to add, how can I generate those numbers moving down? I'm trying to create a loop that will utilize those numbers and perform a math function with each different value.

Comment: @Shark, they _are_ already "moving down" (decreasing): `5` is generated first, then comes `6`, and so on. They are generated from `Actual - n` down to `Actual + n + 1`. This can be changed using the `step` argument of `range`.

Answer (score 1):

ForceBru has already shown a pythonic solution to your problem. I only want to add that your original code works as intended after some minor tweaks:

```
n = 2
def price(sprice):
    sprice -= n # short way to say: sprice = sprice - n
    for i in range(n*2+1): # +1 required as in 1-argument range it is exclusive
        sprice = sprice + 1
        print(sprice)
price(200)
```

Output:

```
199
200
201
202
203
```

Note that Python recognizes `*` is to be executed before `+` independently from its order. Hence you might write `1+n*2` in place of `n*2+1`.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much!